# Jquery UI Drag N Drop duplication issue

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

[Here is the link to my page.](http://revuhree.com/stack) I am having an issue with the jQuery UI drag n drop functionality. I need it to be able to drag multiple of the same item to the container next to it, and all me to reorder them.

So far it allows me to drag and drop 3 as i set in the code, but the problem is when i drag anything else into the box and try to reorder the list, the current list item i am trying to drag duplicate itself until there are 3 before it allows me to reorder them. Any help in preventing duplication unless I am dragging from the container on the left?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="products" class="column large-4 row">
    <h1 class="ui-widget-header">Drag hiring steps to the box on the right.</h1>
    <div class="ui-widget-content">
        <ul>
            <li data-id="1"><span>Phone Interview</span></li>
            <li data-id="2"><span>In-Person Interview</span></li>
            <li data-id="3"><span>Technical Test</span></li>
            <li data-id="4"><span>Personality Test</span></li>
            <li data-id="5"><span>Background Check</span></li>
            <li data-id="6"><span>Drug Test</span></li>
            <li data-id="7"><span contenteditable>Custom Addition</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="shoppingCart1" class="shoppingCart column large-6 push-1">
    <h1 class="ui-widget-header">Drag &amp; drop steps to reorder the hiring process.</h1>
    <div class="ui-widget-content">
        <ol>

        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my JS:

```
var $start_counter = $( "#event-start" ),
$drag_counter = $( "#event-drag" ),
$stop_counter = $( "#event-stop" ),
counts = [ 0, 0, 0 ];
$("#products li").draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "url(grab.cur), url(img/hand.png), auto",
    start: function() {
        var dd = $(this).text();
        console.log( dd + ' is dragging');
    }
});

$(".shoppingCart ol").droppable({
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var self = $(this);
        self.find(".placeholder").remove();
        var productid = ui.draggable.attr("data-id");
        if (self.find("[data-id=" + productid + "]").length == 3) return;

        $("<li></li>", {
            "text": ui.draggable.text(),
            "data-id": productid,
            "class": 'editable'
        }).appendTo(this);

        $("<span></span>", {
            "class": 'close pull-2'
        }).appendTo('.editable');

        $('.ui-droppable li').wrapInner('<span class="white"> </span>');

        // To remove item from other shopping chart do this
        var cartid = self.closest('.shoppingCart').attr('id');
        $(".shoppingCart:not(#"+cartid+") [data-id="+productid+"]").remove();
    var removeMom = function(el) {
        el.on('click', function() {
            var closeBtn = $(this).parents('.editable');
            closeBtn.slideUp(200, function() { $(this).remove();} );
        })

    }

    $('.ui-draggable, .editable').each(
        function() {
            handTrick( $(this) );
        }
    );

    $('.close').each(
        function() {
            removeMom( $(this) );
        }
    );
}
}).sortable({
items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
sort: function() {
    $(this).removeClass("ui-state-default");
}
});

var removeMom = function(el) {
el.on('click', function() {
    var closeBtn = $(this).parents('.editable');
    closeBtn.remove();
})

}

var handTrick = function(el) {
el.on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).css({cursor: "pointer"});
});
el.on('mouseoout', function() {
    $(this).css({cursor: "auto"});
});
el.on('mousedown', function() {
    $(this).css({cursor: "url(grab.cur), url(img/hand.png), auto"});
});
el.on('mouseup', function() {
    $(this).css({cursor: "pointer"});
});

}

$('.close').each(
function() {
    removeMom( $(this) );
}
);

$('.ui-draggable').each(
function() {
    handTrick( $(this) );
}
);

var yy = $('.ui-widget-content').height();
$('.ui-droppable').css('min-height', yy);
```

CSS you can see for yourself when you go to the page. I hope someone can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. I had to wrap the drop in a conditional. It still allows me to drop into the container without each item being able to duplicate itself when dragged while, inside the container.

```
if(!ui.draggable.hasClass('editable')){
        var self = $(this);
        var productid = ui.draggable.attr("data-id");
        if (self.find("[data-id=" + productid + "]").length == 9) return;

        $("<li></li>", {
            "text": ui.draggable.text(),
            "data-id": productid,
            "class": 'editable',
        }).appendTo(this);
        $("<span></span>", {
            "class": 'close pull-2'
        }).appendTo('.editable');
        $('.ui-droppable li').wrapInner('<span class="white"> </span>');

        var cartid = self.closest('.shoppingCart').attr('id');
        $(".shoppingCart:not(#"+cartid+") [data-id="+productid+"]").remove();



        var removeMom = function(el) {
            el.on('click', function() {
                var closeBtn = $(this).parents('.editable');
                closeBtn.slideUp(200, function() { $(this).remove();} );
            })

        }

        $('.ui-draggable, .editable').each(
            function() {
                handTrick( $(this) );
            }
        );

        $('.close').each(
            function() {
                removeMom( $(this) );
            }
        );
}
```

Comment: did you skip this line "self.find(".placeholder").remove();" on purpose or mistake?